# Extended Request missing data when reaching controller with type-hint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

A lot of pieces to this so here's the meat. Code very slightly tweaked for brevity.

Extended class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Http\Request as LaravelRequest;

class Request extends LaravelRequest
{
}
```

Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Http\Request as CustomizedRequest;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomizeRequest
{
    protected $app;
    protected $customizedRequest;

    public function __construct(Application $app, CustomizedRequest $customizedRequest){
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->customizedRequest = $customizedRequest;
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
        $this->app->instance(
            'request',
            Request::createFrom($request, $this->customizedRequest);
        );
        return $next($this->customizedRequest);
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/books1/{id}',[BookController::class, 'frontend1']);
Route::get('/books2/{id}',[BookController::class, 'frontend2']);
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Book;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function frontend1(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
        dump($request);
        dump($request->all());
        dump($request->route('id'));
        return Book::all();
    }

    public function frontend2(\App\Http\Request $request){
        dump($request);
        dump($request->all());
        dump($request->route('id'));
        return Book::all();
    }
}
```

The `/books1/5?foo=bar` and `frontend1()` path works. `$request` is populated as expected.

[image: Populated Correctly]

The `/books2/5?foo=bar` and `frontend2()` path is broken. `$request` has vast amounts of missing data, like it was instantiated with nothing.

[image: Populated Incorrectly]

Evidently if I type-hint my subclass instead of the more generic parent, it's causing some kind of broken instantiation. From an OO perspective I think this should be perfectly fine and I do specifically need my subclass being provided so prefer that type-hint. Is something deep within Laravel tripping this up? Is this some obscure PHP behavior I haven't seen before?

Comment: I'll explain you what happen, but it will be a little bit complicated so you might read this while i'm writting the answer: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container, you'll need to understand how the service container works in order to understand what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of tricky.

First of all, you need to be familiar with the service container and dependency injection. Here is the full doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container

---

When you type hint a class inside a controller method, Laravel will try to understand what it should do with it.

If nothing is registered inside the service container, it will try to make a new instance of it.

`\Illuminate\Http\Request` is bound as a singleton (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#binding-a-singleton).

While a simple bind will return a new instance at each call, a singleton will always return the exact same instance.

Here is a quick demo:

`\App\Models\User::class` is a class that is not explicitly bound.

When you try to resolve it using the service container, it will not find it and will try to make a new instance:

```php
$u1 = app(\App\Models\User::class);
// Searching \App\Models\User::class...
// Cannot find \App\Models\User::class...
// returning new \App\Models\User();

$u2 = app(\App\Models\User::class);
// same process again

$u3 = app(\App\Models\User::class);
// and again


// You can check these instances are indeed different by checking their hash:
dd(
   spl_object_hash($u1), // 000000004af5213500000000220f0bc0 (52135)
   spl_object_hash($u2), // 000000004af5213400000000220f0bc0 (52134)
   spl_object_hash($u3)  // 000000004af5213700000000220f0bc0 (52137)
);
```

But since `\Illuminate\Http\Request::class` is bound by Laravel, it follows a different path:

```php
$r1 = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
// Searching \Illuminate\Http\Request::class...
// Found it! Bound as a singleton.
// returning new \Illuminate\Http\Request() and storing the 
// instance in case it is required again later;

$r2 = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
// Searching \Illuminate\Http\Request::class...
// Found it and already called! Returning the stored instance ($r1)

$r3 = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
// Searching \Illuminate\Http\Request::class...
// Found it and already called! Returning the stored instance ($r1)


// Their hash are the same
dd(
   spl_object_hash($u1), // 0000000011f522cf0000000077704cd1
   spl_object_hash($u2), // 0000000011f522cf0000000077704cd1
   spl_object_hash($u3)  // 0000000011f522cf0000000077704cd1
);
```

Now, what's happening?

Under the hood, when a new request is made to your app and before hitting the controller method, Laravel will do a lot of things to prepare the `\Illuminate\Http\Request` instance.

For instance, it will setup the route resolver inside `Illuminate\Routing\Router`:

```php
/**
     * Return the response for the given route.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function runRoute(Request $request, Route $route)
    {

// here

        $request->setRouteResolver(function () use ($route) {
            return $route;
        });

//

        $this->events->dispatch(new RouteMatched($route, $request));


        return $this->prepareResponse($request,
            $this->runRouteWithinStack($route, $request)
        );
    }
```

Each time Laravel internally call a method like this:

```php
protected function method(Request $request){
     // do something to $request
}
```

`$request` is always the same instance, because it is bound as a singleton.

---

We are now in your controller.

```php
    public function frontend1(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
        // Searching \Illuminate\Http\Request::class...
        // Found it and already called! 
        // Returning the stored instance that has been prepared through all
        // Laravel core classes


        dump($request);
        dump($request->all());  //well prepared
        dump($request->route('id'));  //well setup
        return Book::all();
    }

    public function frontend2(\App\Http\Request $request){
        // Searching \App\Http\Request::class...
        // Cannot find \App\Http\Request::class...
        // returning new \App\Http\Request();

        dump($request);
        dump($request->all());  //nothing
        dump($request->route('id')); //empty
        return Book::all();
    }
```

#### If you are still here, how to solve this problem?

The easiest way is to use a `FormRequest`, initially designed to handle form validation, but if you return an empty rules array, you should be able to do everything you did with your custom `\App\Http\Request` instance:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class Request extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Try again, everything should work fine, since this is a feature specially designed to replace the initial `\Illuminate\Http\Request` object.

The full doc is here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: This is brilliant and should be referenced in any conversation about extending `Request`, which seems to be a rather common practice. The 8.x docs frustratingly don't cover extending it (older versions do) and there are years of now-obsolete explanations out there for extending `Request` that can easily mislead people. I did find one other reference towards extending `FormRequest`, instead, but without the context to explain *why* and when I got exceptions around `rules()` I jumped out of that tangent. In any case, thanks for this. This is the most helpful reply I've ever gotten here.

Comment: Now that I've digested this some, you said this is the "easiest way", and extending `FormRequest` instead seems to be a way to get around this problem that's uniquely available to `Request`. I didn't spot anything within `FormRequest` to explain why this works so I'm assuming something someplace else knows how to handle it? Is that something that could be configured to accept my `Request` subclass as well, the "right way?"

Comment: Glad it helped! The other way of making it work would be to replace the initial singleton bind, so everytime Laravel try to inject `\Illuminate\Http\Request`, it injects `\App\Http\Request`. In this specific case, I'm having trouble making it work. Another way of extending (sort of) the request class would be to create macros (Request use the macroable trait). Take a look at the doc (this is for collection but you can do the exact same thing with Request) : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#extending-collections

Comment: Thanks. I've seen mention of those options, too, but usually in the context of older Laravel versions. It seems like replacing the singleton would be the most straightforward approach but also a bit more abrasive than macros. But I'm not sure macros will offer the level of customization I'm going for. In any case those discussions would be going beyond the scope of this question. Thanks again!